How to start non-headless puppeteer in background on Mac OS?
When Puppeteer starts in non-headless mode, the new Chrome brought to the front of the screen and captures the focus, overriding currently active window.
I would like to keep it visible with headless: false, but stayed in the background, behind other windows. Or, keep it in tray, or launch in another, inactive desk window (mac os allows to use multiple windows).

Puppeteer does not provide such an option.

Since your on macos, why not send an Command + Tab to instanly move back to your previous window.
Or call it twice to go to another window...
Below an example, but this idea can be extended with AppleScript, you could for example find a window by name and bring that to the front, or call Command + H to minimalize the current window.

We can call add the following AppleScript call to send a Command + Tab :
tell application "System Events"
    key down command
    keystroke tab
    key up command
end tell

But lets make that a single line  and call it via osascript:
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'key down command' -e 'keystroke tab' -e 'key up command' -e 'end tell'


Implementing this in the first puppeteer example, we get:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { exec, spawn } from 'child_process'

(async () => {
  // Launch the browser and open a new blank page
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Navigate the page to a URL
  await page.goto('https://developer.chrome.com/');

  exec(`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'key down command' -e 'keystroke tab' -e 'key up command' -e 'end tell'`)

  // Set screen size
  await page.setViewport({width: 1080, height: 1024});

  // Type into search box
  await page.type('.devsite-search-field', 'automate beyond recorder');

  await new Promise(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(resolve, 20000)
   });

  await browser.close();
})();

